# Spring cloud config specify netmask

Tags: java, spring, microservices, netflix-eureka, rancher

I'm trying to deploy a cluster of microservices using `Rancher` on multiple Amazon instances.

A problem that I've encountered is that every docker container now has 2 IP addresses; 1 local IP address, defined by docker itself, and another IP address that is routed to the Rancher bridge.

```
45: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:b4:d3:52:be:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.4/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.42.232.123/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The IP address defined by `Rancher` is the one in the `10.42.*.*` range and is unique for every container, this is why I want to let my Spring cloud configs use this IP address.

No I've found that you can specify in the config which interface to use, but is it also possible to specify the subnet? Because both IP's are on the same interface (`eth0`) but the services should use the 10.42.*.* (e.g. to register themselves with at the discovery service).

I hope someone can help me further with this.

Relevant part of my config:

```
eureka:
    instance:
        preferIpAddress: true
```

(Eureka uses the same config as spring cloud)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rancher-metadata api like this:

`http://rancher-metadata/latest/self/container/service_name`

you can get the `service_name`, `hostname`, `primary_ip` and others.

So you can use in Dockerfile like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a solution similar De Zhang posted using the IP address set by rancher on the IPSec managed network with this mini script as the entrypoint of the image:

```
echo "Setting rancher managed ip address on MANAGED_IP environment variable"
export MANAGED_IP=$(curl --retry 5 --connect-timeout 3 -s 169.254.169.250/latest/self/container/primary_ip)
echo "Rancher IP is ${MANAGED_IP}"
java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

Before the application bootstrap this set the IP address obtained from the metadata service and store it in the environment variable MANAGED_IP, then print it.

My config repo (I'm using Spring Cloud Config Server) looks like this

```
eureka:
  {...}
  shouldUseDns: false
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    ip-address: ${MANAGED_IP}
```